# a for loop to pull df.columns into a custom code

Tags: python, pandas, csv

please be gentle total Python newbie, I'm currently writing a script which is turning out to be very long and i thought there *must!* be a for loop method to make this easier. I'm currently going through a CSV, pulling the header titles and placing it within a str.replace code, manually.

df['Col 1'] = df['Col 1'].str.replace('text','replacement')

I figured it would start like this.. but no idea how to proceed!

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
for row in df.columns:
   if (df[,:] =...
```

Sorry I know this probably looks terrible, but this is all I could fathom with my limited knowledge!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `df = df.replace('text','replacement')` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: What's the difference ? this works for me when I test in Juypter (str.replace) so it's not an issue,

Comment: `df['Col 1'] = df['Col 1'].str.replace('text','replacement')` replace only one column, `df = df.replace('text','replacement')` replace all columns in dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jezrael comment solved it much more ellegantly.

But, in case you needed specific code for each column it would go something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace('text','replacement')
```

Comment: Cheers this is very helpful exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No worries! We've all been there.

Your import statement should be lowercase: `import pandas as pd`

In your for loop, I think there's a misunderstanding of what you'll be iterating over. The `for row in df.columns` will iterate over the column names, not the rows.

Is it correct to say that you'd like to convert the column names to strings?

Comment: my column names are already strings and list correctly within the CSV, however the values within the columns are wrong so i'm just doing some tidying up. What I want to do is something like

import pandas as pd
df = read_csv('file.csv')
df.columns
['col a', 'col b', 'col c'] * 210 (these are all str values)

I would like to write a loop method/fuction to write all the column names into the str string above if that makes sense?

Comment: Gotcha. So I would do `for col in df.columms: df[col].replace('text', 'replacement')` to answer your original question. It might also be of interest to you to check out the comment that suggests `df.replace(...)` on the whole dataframe instead of iterating over columns.

Comment: Many thanks, however the change in each column is unique, for example col 1 = replacement.a and so forth, so that's why I probably went with str.replace as opposed to a df.replace

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',usecols=['List of column names you want to use from your csv'],
names=['list of names of column you want your pandas df to have'])
```

You should read the docs and identify the fields that are important in your case.

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do a multiple-column replacement in one shot with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by passing in a dictionary.

Say you want to replace `t1` with `r1` in column `a`; `t2` with `r2` in column `b`, you can do

```
df.replace({"a":{"t1":"r1"}, "b":{"t2":"r2"}})
```

Comment: This seems much more logical, a question I have is, is there a way to index the columns to see what letter corresponds with each column? or must you list each column name manually? 

for example my csv has 300+ columns, i'm deleting a few and merging others the most manual part is changing most answers from "yes" to a more appropriate string.

Comment: @Datanovice here the letters are the column names. So it will look into column `a` and `b`. Do I answer your question?

Comment: @Datanovice I think you need to build the dictionary manually.  I am not clear for your problem: not sure whether there are side effect to do replacement at once. You can certainly replace all "yes" to something with a call, but I don't know whether that will change some part that you don't want to change as you require column by column replacement.

Comment: that does indeed answer my questions. Thanks for your help this was extremely educational.